# How to draw form text in a border less form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have border less form (FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None)..when I set this it removes the default drawn form text from form...

So I use paint event and draw string method to draw my custom text at the top left...

What I want to do is when you resize a sizable form if it's text length is greater than form then you will be see a 3 dot lines at the last of the text indicating text length is greater than form...

I want to achieve that in border less form like when I drawn string in a border less form and it it's length is greater than form then it should show a 3 dot lines at last of the text..

If you want I can give you the code

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is *"the default drawn form text"*? Also, relevant code is almost always required to get a good answer.

Comment: We can reduce this question to: How to draw ellipsis when text to draw is wider than draw area? - Anything else is only noise

Comment: Get the graphics context, use the DrawString method.

Comment: [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext) with [TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textformatflags)

Comment: Note that you can just use a Label with [`AutoEllipsis = true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.autoellipsis) and `AutoSize = false`, It's the same thing as using TextRenderer with that flag set.